# just use second item from an array

Tags: javascript, imacros

In imacros, I need to split a piece of text from the clipboard into 2 parts and then use the second part.
This is what I have already:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!CLIPBOARD}}\"; s.split(\"(B)\",1); var r = s[1];r ")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
```

If I insert:
"Abcde (B) FGHIJ"
what I would expect is a prompt with "FGHIJ" as the second item in the array
but what I get is "b" as the second letter.

How do I get the second item?

If you need it, here's the whole macro:

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Neue<SP>Frage...<SP>
PROMPT "Kopiere die neue Frage!"
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!CLIPBOARD}}\"; s.split(\"(B)\",1); var r = s[1];r ")
PROMPT {{!VAR1}}
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=ID:question CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:answer1 CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:answer2 CONTENT=test
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:answer3 CONTENT=test   
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:answer4 CONTENT=dd
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:answer5 CONTENT=dd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `SET` line to:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!CLIPBOARD}}\"; s = s.split(\"(B)\"); var r = s[1];r ")
```

`split` doesn't modify the string it is called from. Also, I removed the limit of `1` you passed in to the `split` method, because that will make it only return the first index of the resulting array created by the split. In your example, it would return `[Abcde ]`, instead of `[Abcde ,  FGHIJ]`

Check out info about the `split` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split